# Thunderbolt Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, thunderbolt

After last updates in Ubuntu 19.04 Thunderbolt doesn't work correctly. Mouse and keyboard don't work if you use Thunderbolt before loading the system.

[image]

Comment: Boot with the previous kernel version in Grub's Advanced Options menu.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have `thunderbolt-tools` package installed. If not, you can install it with the command below :

```
sudo apt-get install -y thunderbolt-tools
```